grpc-web client using go?
I am trying to connect to a grpc-web server using go grpc client. After many failed attempts, I understand the grpc-web and grpc is different and grpc client cannot connect to grpc-web server.
I see there is https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/ library to create grpc-web go server but I found very little information in the web about creating a grpc-web go client.
I modified the https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/examples/helloworld/greeter_server/main.go to serve grpc-web.
/*
 *
 * Copyright 2015 gRPC authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 */

// Package main implements a server for Greeter service.
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/go/grpcweb"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    pb "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld"
)

var (
    port = flag.Int("port", 50051, "The server port")
)

// server is used to implement helloworld.GreeterServer.
type server struct {
    pb.UnimplementedGreeterServer
}

// SayHello implements helloworld.GreeterServer

func (s *server) SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *pb.HelloRequest) (*pb.HelloReply, error) {
    log.Printf("Received: %v", in.GetName())
    return &pb.HelloReply{Message: "Hello " + in.GetName()}, nil
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterGreeterServer(s, &server{})
    // gRPC web code
    grpcWebServer := grpcweb.WrapServer(
        s,
        // Enable CORS
        grpcweb.WithOriginFunc(func(origin string) bool { return true }),
    )

    srv := &http.Server{
        Handler: grpcWebServer,
        Addr:    fmt.Sprintf("localhost:%d", *port),
    }

    log.Printf("http server listening at %v", srv.Addr)
    if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}

I am using this as my example to create go grpc-web client. Can anyone help me come up with a grpc-web go client?
It is important to note that I don't have control over the grpc-web server and I need to connect to grpc-web using the go client not any other web client like JS.

improbable-eng/grpc-web is in maintenance mode and you should consider using grpc-web.
See gRPC-Web tutorial
gRPC-Web does not directly expose an API so it is not practical to consider writing a (Go) client against a gRPC-Web implementation. The gRPC-Web implementation is itself a client to a gRPC server.
gRPC-Web exists because browsers haven't supported the full feature set of HTTP/2 that is required by gRPC. gRPC-Web provides a shim for the functionality enabling you to use protobuf sources, protobuf messages and a familiar API to build JavaScript (i.e. Web) clients.
You could potentially extend a gRPC-Web JavaScript client to publish an API and then consume this from e.g. Go but this would be unwieldy.
There is another mechanism by which gRPC services may be exposed to non-gRPC clients. This is called gRPC/JSON transcoding. This requires that the protobuf sources be annotated to include descriptions of the mapping between gRPC and REST|JSON and a proxy (often Envoy) that translates between the protocols but this mechanism provides an HTTP/REST API alongside gRPC services|methods. Google has used this mechanism extensively to publish its services as both gRPC and HTTP/REST.
In summary, you could

use an e.g. Go gRPC client to communicate directly with the gRPC server.
implement a gRPC-Web client in JavaScript (!) that communicates through a proxy with the gRPC server.
(discouraged) expose the gRPC-Web client (above) through a HTTP/REST API to a Go HTTP|REST client
use an e.g. Go HTTP|REST client to communicate through a proxy with the gRPC server reconfigured to expose gRPC-JSON transcoding.

